# What do you need to understand the Theory of Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity

If someone has studied calculus, what "instruments" or what fields does one still need to understand the formulas behind the 2 theories of relativity (special and general)? By understand I mean more that the general concept.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: everything is there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_the_mathematics_of_general_relativity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_general_relativity you need to know the special relativity, and the differential manifolds, in particular the Riemann curvature tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-variable, vector and tensor calculus are the basics, differential geometry and Riemann geometry is also important.  Besides mathematics, the basic electromagnetism is necessary.

Comment: the electromagnetism as an introduction for the special relativity ?

Comment: @user1952009 Both SR and GR need EM.  We need covariant formulation of EM in SR.  We also need EM to derive the field equation in GR.

Comment: is it this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Einstein.E2.80.93Maxwell_equations ?

Comment: Yes, see also [$T_{\mu \nu}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)

Comment: well this is $E = mc^2$, but for understanding the Einstein equation at first we don't really care that the electromagnetism can be a source of space-time curvature too, isn't ?

Comment: Yes, somehow.  But it's part of the field equation.

Comment: Electrodynamics isn't a necessary requirement for GR, however I think most physicists agree knowledge of ED is necessary to be a physicist. But you can do GR and cosmology without it